# Why do radeon graphics in a Live USB session work, but in an installation don't?

Tags: 14.04, boot, lubuntu, radeon, apic

When booting a Lubuntu Live session from a USB stick, I get the classic `MP-BIOS bug: 8254 timer not connected to IO-APIC` error, but nevertheless the session starts and the graphics are working like a charm.

When installing Lubuntu from this stick without internet connection, I can't boot anymore. At some point during boot, the screen gets black but starts to brighten slowly. Some pixels start to get green, blue or red.

**How can that be?**

I can start the system in recovery mode or when adding the option "nomodeset" to grub, but, of course, graphics won't work the way they should.

The notebook originally came out with Windows Vista and has a Radeon X1200 card / chip in it.

**UPDATE:**
Once again I tried Lubuntu 16.04, which did not boot at all. Then I tried Lubuntu 17.10 and it booted, I could install it and even the installation now works like a charm. Even did some reboots.

I won't bother anymore with installing 14.04, but maybe someone will find this question someday and can tell me / us **why graphics work(ed) in a Live System, but don't (didn't) in an installation.**

Comment: Have you checked the ISO's MD5SUM?

Comment: Yes, it matches.

Comment: Really going to use 14.04? It'll be EOL in 4 months. There's 16.04.

Comment: I know, I tried 16.04 with other distributions without success.

Comment: Had something similar when trying to install to my daughters Atom based Intel mini ITX computer, had to find and install a graphics driver to make it work. Does the stick work OK on other computers? Some help for Radon see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: I already knew that page. I updated my question.